# Sakai student unable to upload image: FCK Editor image upload error 203

Tags: java, security, sakai

When the student user try to upload image through CKEditor following dialog appeared with an error message.

[image]

I have been searching for a solution for this.still unable to resolve.

> org.sakaiproject.exception.PermissionException
>   user=58095d7f-9abf-405a-a746-b3bdd673f216 lock=content.new
>   resource=/content/group/52b29c56-c607-4c31-966d-e0394a7eeb78/21761483_756386641230111_2474470716028905585_n.jpg
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.content.impl.BaseContentService.unlock(BaseContentService.java:1784)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.content.impl.BaseContentService.addResource(BaseContentService.java:3587)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.content.impl.BaseContentService.addResource(BaseContentService.java:3141)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.content.impl.BaseContentService.addResource(BaseContentService.java:3211)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.content.impl.BaseContentService.addResource(BaseContentService.java:3200)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.connector.fck.FCKConnectorServlet.doPost(FCKConnectorServlet.java:355)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.util.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:709)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you, please, confirm the version of Sakai?

Comment: Where are you even connecting to qa3-us.sakaiproject.org in the screenshot? That server hasn't been accessible for years.

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception, the problem is related to the user's permissions, have you checked it?

[PermissionException](http://source.sakaiproject.org/release/11.4/apidocs/org/sakaiproject/exception/PermissionException.html):

> PermissionException indicates an invalid unlock attempt by a user for a lock and a resource.